# How to connect and run commands in a ubuntu and windows machines?

Tags: linux, windows, amazon-web-services, server

I want to run few scripts (jmeter scripts) in few ***AWS*** *ubuntu* machines and ***windows7*** machines. Usually I use ***WinScp*** (transfer files), ***putty*** (run commands) for linux and ***Remote* *Desktop* *Connection*** for windows machines, to do the work manually.

Now I want to **automate** these processes and would like to know how to achieve that. My intention is to write code to,

1. connect to these machines,
2. copy the scripts,
3. run the scripts,
4. fetch the log files and
5. close the machine

I also want to schedule them. What is the best way of doing this? Also I prefer that the code that I write can be hosted somewhere (so that rest api can be exposed) or called as a direct **library** (API) in my java server.

I know that chef scripts can be written, but want to know any other alternatives. https://www.chef.io/chef/

**Thanks a ton in Advance**.

Comment: Something like cron jobs?

Comment: The cron jobs is just the end part of it. Forget the scheduling, If i understand the way to deploy scripts, that will be sufficient.

Comment: I know for Linux `ssh user@host -p 22 <command>`, where `<command>` can be a script on the remote machine which does step 2 to 4. The `ssh` command automatically outputs the output from the remote machine.